# Google Place Photo API returning 404

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

Google Place Photo API is returning 404 for any photo reference I use. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong

**Nearby Google Request**

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=12.9716,77.5946&radius=5000&keyword=arbor&key={KEY}

**Photo Reference from Nearby Response:**

> CmRZAAAAu3qofo2XYSX74WtaGYIZ6iMA97uXmuJscP6xOW371WVRPpJk5ZscaxSfEYCCVgXgDzGKRC7ajN0dQ2_sECQqlO8F3YNp38VTmLDJ6LB-qMyyrn__-dnquJR_H4EUegt6EhCmHKtr_TcE_1wIAI-4fuCGGhTu9TPV6X9vQ7SgF-npEOssGdzR2A

**Photo Request**

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CmRZAAAAu3qofo2XYSX74WtaGYIZ6iMA97uXmuJscP6xOW371WVRPpJk5ZscaxSfEYCCVgXgDzGKRC7ajN0dQ2_sECQqlO8F3YNp38VTmLDJ6LB-qMyyrn__-dnquJR_H4EUegt6EhCmHKtr_TcE_1wIAI-4fuCGGhTu9TPV6X9vQ7SgF-npEOssGdzR2A&key={KEY}

returns 404. 
Not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has been reported to Google:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37262562

**EDIT**

The issue has now been resolved

Comment: Looks like it has been fixed now. This answer can be a placeholder to show that there always maybe a problem with Google's API itself :D

Comment: Did I link the wrong issue? Yeah... :( https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63298126